# Insert variables into os command

Tags: python, string, variables

I'm a newbie trying to modify the awesome photobooth code by Drumminhands to add a watermark.

I am trying to pass a variable through to the os.command string, but it keeps responding with an error when it is using the exact word 'filename' rather than the value for that variable defined above.

```
for i, filename in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous(file_path + now + '-' + '{counter:02d}.jpg')):
    GPIO.output(led2_pin,True) #turn on the LED
    print(filename)
    watermark = "gm composite /home/pi/photobooth/watermark.png filename filename"
    os.system(watermark)
```

https://github.com/drumminhands/drumminhands_photobooth/blob/master/drumminhands_photobooth.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not support string interpolation directly.  Instead, you need to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert values into strings:

```
watermark = "gm composite /home/pi/photobooth/watermark.png {0} {0}".format(filename)
```